# Good method design when choosing the enum type?

Tags: java, methods

Which approach would be better between the following two? 
I have chosen enums since, in the typical case subtype polymorphishm is the best approach; also this is a typical approach when writing a simple factory method.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeEnum returnAType(String someString) {
        //implementation bellow
   }

   private boolean method1() {
   //...
   }

   private boolean method2() {
   //...
   }

   private boolean method3() {
   //...
   }

}
```

The first implementation of returnATypeMethod; this is faster since it does not call method2 and method3 (and possibly more) if method1 is valid.

```
    public SomeEnum returnAType(String someString) {
        if(method1(someString)) {
            SomeEnum.ENUM1.doSomething();
            return SomeEnum.ENUM1;
        }
        if(method2(someString)) {
            SomeEnum.ENUM2.doSomething();
            return SomeEnum.ENUM2;
        }
        if(method3(someString)) {
            SomeEnum.ENUM3.doSomething();
            return SomeEnum.ENUM3;
        }
        SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM.doSomething();
        return SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM;
   }
```

The second implementation of returnATypeMethod; this is more clear and no code duplicate:

```
    public SomeEnum returnAType(String someString) {
        SomeEnum enumType = SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM;
        if(method1(someString)) {
            enumType = SomeEnum.ENUM1;
        }
        if(method2(someString)) {
            enumType = SomeEnum.ENUM2;            }
        }
        if(method3(someString)) {
            enumType = SomeEnum.ENUM3;
        }
        enumType.doSomething();
        return enumType;
   }
```

Comment: What if method1 and method2 and method3 is true?

Comment: If the return approach is selected then the first is considered; if not, the last one. With an if-else approach (as those suggested bellow) it's like with return - the first is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to use

```
public SomeEnum returnAType(String someString) {
    SomeEnum enumType = method1(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM1 :
                        method2(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM2 :
                        method3(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM3 : SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM;
    enumType.doSomething();
    return enumType;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I find Java enums very confusing, and in general I would suggest to **Try to avoid enums when you are not simply enumerating**. You can organize your code into an interface or an abstract class and several singletons implementing that interface or abstract class. The final design is much cleaner and more understandable.

I warmly suggest to **try to avoid a method which returns T and also calls t.someMethod inside**. This pattern is confusing and misleading again. *Think your returnAType as a factory method for your singletons, the goal of this function is only to return you the right type of singleton*

**If your function does not use some patterns but simple equalities, use a data structure to store the key-value association**. Not EnumMap as someone said, because in EnumMap the Enum is the key, not the value.

In fact, a comment you received by @Peter Lawrey underlined the problem you get if you do not follow the second suggestion: don't write a method which returns t and also produces sides effects through t. My suggestion is to partially follow its advice, but move the side effect outside in this way:

```
// Beautiful and testable with no side-effects

public SomeEnum returnAType(String someString) {
    SomeEnum enumType = method1(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM1 :
                        method2(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM2 :
                        method3(someString) ? SomeEnum.ENUM3 : SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM;

    return enumType;
}

// Do something for real
public void doSomethingWith(String someString) {
    SomeEnum enumType = returnAType(someString);
    enumType.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: How exactly are Enums confusing?

Comment: Enumerations are very good for things who can assume values in a discrete, enumerable set, however in my personal experience they tend to mislead the design and bring people to write code full of switchs and if (because they are enums) . If they are replaced by a class hierarchy and a proper usage of polymorphism and other design patterns such as factory methods, the final design is normally cleaner.

Comment: Except for the headache of writing your own usertype objects for hibernate, and other situations where it's a pain to switch actual implementation objects.  Plus if you really need to, you can add behavior to enum objects (which i wouldn't do unless you really need to, but it can be done).  See this pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/5cRAHY5R

Comment: Ah I thought Hibernate was some 10-years technology which you only read about in textbooks and people have understood ORM are dangerous and harmful :)

Comment: @Edmondo1984: When using enums, you do not have to write lots of if-else; you only have to write them when initializing which is the same as in a typical factory method. In other cases you iterate over Enum.values() and do the operation on all the types.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 you can use `switch` with String :

Class `SomeEnum` elsewhere with Constructor `SomeEnum(Integer) {..;}`.

It can be `private` as in `Pattern.class` example, so it would be `return SomeEnum.set(1);`.

```
public SomeEnum returnAType(final String someString) {
     switch (someString.toLowerCase()) { //toLowerCase() if needed
        case "one":
            return new SomeEnum(1);
            break;
        case "two":
            return new SomeEnum(2);
            break;
        case "three":
            return new SomeEnum(3);
            break;
        default: 
            return new SomeEnum(-1); // or zero or Integer.[MIN|MAX]_VALUE
            break;
      }
}
```

Then you can use SomeEnum as you want.

Some model does not like intermediate returns so, you can add a temporary SomeEnum inside and return it at the end.

With `typeOf SomeEnum` is `enum`

```
public SomeEnum returnAType(final String someString) {
     switch (someString.toLowerCase()) { //toLowerCase() if needed
        case "one":
            return SomeEnum.ENUM1;
            // break; // Normaly break; is unused, you can  remove it
        case "two":
            return SomeEnum.ENUM2;
        case "three":
            return SomeEnum.ENUM3;
        default: 
            return SomeEnum.DEFAULT_ENUM; 
      }
}
```

Comment: Class SomeEnum it's actually an enum; you do not have public constructor.